# Problem with downloading language local experience file using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-10, intune

I use a fantastic script to download LXP files from microsoft and install them. This script works fine with languages like: en-us, pl-pl, zh-tw, zh-cn, fr-fr, ja-jp and maybe more BUT there is a strange issue with languages like italian (it-it), spanish (es-es) and portuguese (pt-pt). The script shows an error that the  Invoke-WebRequest can't connect to the server and the rest of script fails because next variables are empty. Maybe sb will have an idea how to solve it.

There is a script I am talking about with es-es language:

```
# the language we want as new default
$language = "es-ES"

Start-Transcript -Path "$env:TEMP\LXP-SystemContext-Installer-$language.log" | Out-Null

# https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/deutsch-local-experience-pack/9p6ct0slw589
$applicationId = "9NWVGWLHPB1Z" # spanish

$webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bspmts.mp.microsoft.com/v1/public/catalog/Retail/Products/$applicationId/applockerdata"
$packageFamilyName = ($webpage | ConvertFrom-JSON).packageFamilyName

$skuId = 0016

$geoId = 217  # Spain

$inputLanguageID = "0c0a:0000040a" # es-es

# custom folder for temp scripts
"...creating custom temp script folder"
$scriptFolderPath = "$env:SystemDrive\ProgramData\CustomTempScripts"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $scriptFolderPath
"`n"

$languageXmlPath = $(Join-Path -Path $scriptFolderPath -ChildPath "MUI.xml")
# language xml definition for intl.cpl call to switch the language 'welcome screen' and 'new user' defaults
$languageXml = @"
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">

    <!-- user list -->
    <gs:UserList>
        <gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/>
    </gs:UserList>

    <!-- GeoID -->
    <gs:LocationPreferences>
        <gs:GeoID Value="$geoId"/>
    </gs:LocationPreferences>

    <!-- UI Language Preferences -->
    <gs:MUILanguagePreferences>
        <gs:MUILanguage Value="$language"/>
    </gs:MUILanguagePreferences>

    <!-- system locale -->
    <gs:SystemLocale Name="$language"/>

    <!-- input preferences -->
    <gs:InputPreferences>
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="$inputLanguageID" Default="true"/>
    </gs:InputPreferences>

    <!-- user locale -->
    <gs:UserLocale>
        <gs:Locale Name="$language" SetAsCurrent="true" ResetAllSettings="false"/>
    </gs:UserLocale>

</gs:GlobalizationServices>
"@

$userConfigScriptPath = $(Join-Path -Path $scriptFolderPath -ChildPath "UserConfig.ps1")
# we could encode the complete script to prevent the escaping of $, but I found it easier to maintain
# to not encode. I do not have to decode/encode all the time for modifications.
$userConfigScript = @"
`$language = "$language"

Start-Transcript -Path "`$env:TEMP\LXP-UserSession-Config-`$language.log" | Out-Null

`$geoId = $geoId

"explicitly register the LXP in current user session (Add-AppxPackage -Register ...)"
`$appxLxpPath = (Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object Name -Like *LanguageExperiencePack`$language).InstallLocation
Add-AppxPackage -Register -Path "`$appxLxpPath\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode

# important for regional change like date and time...
"Set-WinUILanguageOverride = `$language"
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language `$language

"Set-WinUserLanguageList = `$language"

#Set-WinUserLanguageList `$language -Force
# changed handling due to new knowledge :-)
# https://oliverkieselbach.com/2021/01/13/company-portal-stuck-in-a-different-language/

`$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
`$UserLanguageList = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language `$language
`$UserLanguageList += `$OldList | where { `$_.LanguageTag -ne `$language }
"Setting new user language list:"
`$UserLanguageList | select LanguageTag
""
"Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList ..."
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList `$UserLanguageList -Force

"Set-WinSystemLocale = `$language"
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale `$language

"Set-Culture = `$language"
Set-Culture -CultureInfo `$language

"Set-WinHomeLocation = `$geoId"
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId `$geoId

Stop-Transcript -Verbose
"@

Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $language -Force

$userConfigScriptHiddenStarterPath = $(Join-Path -Path $scriptFolderPath -ChildPath "UserConfigHiddenStarter.vbs")
$userConfigScriptHiddenStarter = @"
sCmd = "powershell.exe -ex bypass -file $userConfigScriptPath"
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run sCmd,0,true
"@


"...set reg key: BlockCleanupOfUnusedPreinstalledLangPacks = 1"
& REG add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Control Panel\International" /v BlockCleanupOfUnusedPreinstalledLangPacks /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
"`n"

$packageName = "Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePack$language"
# check for installed Language Experience Pack (LXP), maybe already installed?
$status = $(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name $packageName).Status

# create CIM session here as we need it for Store updates as well
$session = New-CimSession

try {
    if ($status -ne "Ok")
    {
        try {
            
            $namespaceName = "root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
            $omaUri = "./Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation"
            $newInstance = New-Object Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance "MDM_EnterpriseModernAppManagement_AppInstallation01_01", $namespaceName
            $property = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimProperty]::Create("ParentID", $omaUri, "string", "Key")
            $newInstance.CimInstanceProperties.Add($property)
            $property = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimProperty]::Create("InstanceID", $packageFamilyName, "String", "Key")
            $newInstance.CimInstanceProperties.Add($property)

            $flags = 0
            $paramValue = [Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($('<Application id="{0}" flags="{1}" skuid="{2}"/>' -f $applicationId, $flags, $skuId))
            $params = New-Object Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimMethodParametersCollection
            $param = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimMethodParameter]::Create("param", $paramValue, "String", "In")
            $params.Add($param)

            # we create the MDM instance and trigger the StoreInstallMethod to finally download the LXP
            $instance = $session.CreateInstance($namespaceName, $newInstance)
            $result = $session.InvokeMethod($namespaceName, $instance, "StoreInstallMethod", $params)
            "...Language Experience Pack install process triggered via MDM/StoreInstall method"
        }
        catch [Exception] {
            write-host $_ | out-string
            $exitcode = 1
        }
    }

    if (($result.ReturnValue.Value -eq 0) -or ($status -eq "Ok")) {

        if ($status -ne "Ok")
        {
            "...busy wait until language pack found, max 15 min."
            $counter=0
            do {
                Start-Sleep 10
                $counter++

                # check for installed Language Experience Pack (LXP)
                $status = $(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name $packageName).Status
            
            } while ($status -ne "Ok" -and $counter -ne 90) # 90x10s sleep => 900s => 15 min. max wait time!
        }

        # print some LXP package details for the log
        Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name $packageName

        if ($status -eq "Ok") {
            "...found Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePack$language with Status=Ok"
            "...trigger install for language FOD packages"

            # add Windows capabilities / FODs to avoid UAC dialog after restart
            # Parameter -Online will reach out to Windows Update to get the latest correct source files
            Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -ilike "Language.*~~~$($language)~*" | ForEach-Object {
                if ($_.State -ine "Installed") {
                    "Adding windows capability '$($_.Name)'..."
                    $_ | Add-WindowsCapability -Online | Out-Null
                }
                else {
                    "Windows capability '$($_.Name)' is already installed.`n"
                }
            }
            "`n"           

        
            "...trigger language change for current user session via ScheduledTask = LXP-UserSession-Config-$language"
            Out-File -FilePath $userConfigScriptPath -InputObject $userConfigScript -Encoding ascii
            Out-File -FilePath $userConfigScriptHiddenStarterPath -InputObject $userConfigScriptHiddenStarter -Encoding ascii

            # REMARK: usag of wscript as hidden starter may be blocked because of security restrictions like AppLocker, ASR, etc...
            #         switch to PowerShell if this represents a problem in your environment.
            $taskName = "LXP-UserSession-Config-$language"
            $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "wscript.exe" -Argument "$userConfigScriptHiddenStarterPath"
            $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
            $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -expand UserName)
            $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries
            $task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Settings $settings
            Register-ScheduledTask $taskName -InputObject $task
            Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName

            Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

            Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false

            # trigger 'LanguageComponentsInstaller\ReconcileLanguageResources' otherwise 'Windows Settings' need a long time to change finally
            "...trigger ScheduledTask = LanguageComponentsInstaller\ReconcileLanguageResources"
            Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\Microsoft\Windows\LanguageComponentsInstaller\ReconcileLanguageResources"

            Start-Sleep 10

            # change 'welcome screen' and 'new user' language defaults
            "...trigger language change for welcome screen and new user defaults"
            Out-File -FilePath $languageXmlPath -InputObject $languageXml -Encoding ascii

            # check eventlog 'Microsoft-Windows-Internationl/Operational' for troubleshooting
            & $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"$languageXmlPath`""

            # trigger store updates, there might be new app versions due to the language change
            "...trigger MS Store updates for app updates"
            Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap" -ClassName "MDM_EnterpriseModernAppManagement_AppManagement01" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "UpdateScanMethod"

            $exitcode = 0
        }
    }
    else {
        $exitcode = 1
    }

    "...cleanup and finish"
    try {
        $session.DeleteInstance($namespaceName, $instance) | Out-Null
        Remove-CimSession -CimSession $session
    } catch {}
    
    Remove-Item -Path $scriptFolderPath -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch [Exception] {
    # maybe a left over  to clean, but prevent aditional errors and set exitcode
    try {
        $session.DeleteInstance($namespaceName, $instance) | Out-Null
    } catch {}

    $exitcode = 1
}

if ($exitcode -eq 0) {
    $installed = 1
}
else {
    $installed = 0
}
# IME app install runs by default in 32-bit so we write explicitly to 64-bit registry
& REG add "HKLM\Software\MyIntuneApps" /v "SetLanguage-$language" /t REG_DWORD /d $installed /f /reg:64 | Out-Null

Stop-Transcript -Verbose

exit $exitcode
```

I tried to find my mistakes in ID etc also checking if the requested language is available (and it is!). I tried to run the invoke-webrequest alone and it also works.

The error msg:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to remote server"
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to remote server
At C:\Windows\IMECache\ffa6ea3b-604e-41c3-98b9-dd30e2f9c714_1\languagechange.ps1:47 char:12
+ $webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bspmts.mp ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExcep
tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to remote server
At C:\Windows\IMECache\ffa6ea3b-604e-41c3-98b9-dd30e2f9c714_1\languagechange.ps1:47 char:12
+ $webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bspmts.mp ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Windows\IMECache\ffa6ea3b-604e-41c3-98b9-dd30e2f9c714_1\languagechange.ps1:48 char:34
+ $packageFamilyName = ($webpage | ConvertFrom-JSON).packageFamilyName
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJs
onCommand
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Windows\IMECache\ffa6ea3b-604e-41c3-98b9-dd30e2f9c714_1\languagechange.ps1:48 char:34
+ $packageFamilyName = ($webpage | ConvertFrom-JSON).packageFamilyName
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFrom
   JsonCommand
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error message in full :)

Comment: The `Invoke-WebRequest` seems to work fine as-is for the spanish and deutsch application IDs listed. Is there a simple way to reproduce the error?

Comment: I already added the error I received. @Cpt.Whale you tried it and it works for you with the Spanish language?

Comment: @goraldave yes, it works for me just copying the 2 app id and iwr lines from the question. Can you open the url in a browser?  https://bspmts.mp.microsoft.com/v1/public/catalog/Retail/Products/9NWVGWLHPb1z/applockerdata "Unable to connect" usually means an issue at a lower level than powershell, like network/proxy problems

Comment: @Cpt.Whale yeah, I can open that link and manually download that .json file. If I can change the language for other languages like pl, en, fr, Chinese, etc so why is there a problem with es-es, pt-pt, and it-it? Strange. Shouldn't I have the proxy problem with others also?